# Soundpool: Bad volume value and Error create audio track?

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I am doing soundpool application, I am able to success to compile the application but I get some error. I have 16 sound in raw folder with .ogg format. I dont know limit for soundpool resource. Application loads the sound sometimes but stop for a long time in out speaker.

Following is error code :

```
bad volume value, error creating AudioTrack, AudioFlinger could not create track status: -12
```

This my code :

```
private SoundPool spool;
private SoundPool spool2;
private SoundPool spool3;
private SoundPool spool4;
private SoundPool spool5;
private SoundPool spool6;
private SoundPool spool7;
private SoundPool spool8;
private SoundPool spool9;
private SoundPool spool10;
private SoundPool spool11;
private SoundPool spool12;
private SoundPool spool13;
private SoundPool spool14;
private SoundPool spool15;
private SoundPool spool16;

private int soundID;
private int soundID2;
private int soundID3;
private int soundID4;
private int soundID5;
private int soundID6;
private int soundID7;
private int soundID8;
private int soundID9;
private int soundID10;
private int soundID11;
private int soundID12;
private int soundID13;
private int soundID14;
private int soundID15;
private int soundID16;

;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.talempong);

    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID = spool.load(this, R.raw.doo, 1);

   ImageButton Button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool2 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID2 = spool2.load(this, R.raw.re, 1);

    ImageButton Button2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton2);
    Button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound2();
        }
});
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool3 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID3 = spool3.load(this, R.raw.mi, 1);

   ImageButton Button3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton3);
    Button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound3();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool4 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID4 = spool4.load(this, R.raw.fa, 1);

   ImageButton Button4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton4);
    Button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound4();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool5 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID5 = spool5.load(this, R.raw.sol, 1);

   ImageButton Button5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton5);
    Button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound5();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool6 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID6 = spool6.load(this, R.raw.la, 1);

   ImageButton Button6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton6);
    Button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound6();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool7 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID7 = spool7.load(this, R.raw.si, 1);

   ImageButton Button7 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton7);
    Button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound7();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool8 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID8 = spool8.load(this, R.raw.do_tinggi, 1);

   ImageButton Button8 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton8);
    Button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound8();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool9 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID9 = spool9.load(this, R.raw.sol_rendah, 1);

   ImageButton Button9 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton9);
    Button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound9();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool10 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID10 = spool10.load(this, R.raw.la_rendah, 1);

   ImageButton Button10 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton10);
    Button10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound10();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool11 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID11 = spool11.load(this, R.raw.si_rendah, 1);

   ImageButton Button11 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton11);
    Button11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound11();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool12 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID12 = spool12.load(this, R.raw.re_kres, 1);

   ImageButton Button12 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton12);
    Button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound12();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool13 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID13 = spool13.load(this, R.raw.fa_kres, 1);

   ImageButton Button13 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton13);
    Button13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound13();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool14 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID14 = spool14.load(this, R.raw.sol_kres, 1);

   ImageButton Button14 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton14);
    Button14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound14();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool15 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID15 = spool15.load(this, R.raw.la_kres, 1);

   ImageButton Button15 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton15);
    Button15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound15();



        }
    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool16 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID16 = spool16.load(this, R.raw.re_tinggi, 1);

   ImageButton Button16 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton16);
    Button16.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound16();

   //Pemanggil audio Talempong       

        }
    });
}
public void Sound(){
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

Comment: You could really clean up your code with some refactoring of common code.

Comment: i try this , but nothing happens..

Comment: you have different idea :) ??

Comment: Try replacing `float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` with `float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) / (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`. The volume passed to the play method can only be between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: I try this, but i have some problem , i know the problem like release on my code,can you tell me how to implement this?